# optaplanner pareto compasion and bendable score

Tags: java, constraints, optaplanner

I am playing with Timed Window VRP and i have a over constrained situation.

In my soft constraints
i have mentioned to reduce miles
Also i dont want free truck if there are a number of tasks assigned to dummy vehicles.

Currently i have kept hard medium and soft.

To achieve, use spare vehicles when dummy vehicles get load, can i approach this using Bendable score? as i dont want to save miles when i can take more task with my free vehicle in this case i am okay to drive more.

Any advise?

Comment: Pareto != bendable score != overconstrained planning. Docs explain all of these concepts one by one.

Comment: Why is that i have a dummy vehicle getting jobs and optaplanner also sets one vehicle free without any tasks? When i checked that vehicle works and have capacity to take some from the dummy vehicles. i am truying to first take many jobs possible then work on distance ... i have union move - Change Move, Swap Move and Tail chain swap move. like to hear some direction.!